# How to wait until my batch file is finished

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, cmd, wait

I'm  doing a program where I need to start cmd and there start up a batch file. The problem  is that I'm using `MyProcess.WaithForexit();`  and  I think it does not wait until the batch file processing is  finished. It just waits until the cmd is closed. My code so far:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo ProcStartInfo =
    new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd");
    ProcStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    ProcStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    ProcStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    ProcStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    System.Diagnostics.Process MyProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    ProcStartInfo.Arguments = "/c start batch.bat ";
    MyProcess.StartInfo = ProcStartInfo;
    MyProcess.Start();
    MyProcess.WaitForExit();
```

I need to wait until the batch file is finished. How do I do that?

Comment: `start` launches the batch and returns. Remove `start`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This actually worked just fine for me:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("myBatFile.bat").WaitForExit();
```

As milton said, adding 'exit' at the end of your batch files is most likely a good idea.

Cheers

Comment: This should be the accepted answer tbh, super simple and effective for what i was looking for +1

Answer (score 3):

The start command has arguments that can make it `WAIT` for the started program to complete.  Edit the arguments as show below to pass '/wait':

```
ProcStartInfo.Arguments = "/c start /wait batch.bat ";
```

I would also suggest that you want your batch file to exit the cmd envirionment so place an 'exit' at the end of the batch.

```
@echo off
rem Do processing
exit
```

This should achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: adding "exit" at the end of the batch file was crucial.