# c# How to stop/pause execution before the next method call

Tags: c#, batch-file

I am a bit of a newbie with C# and hoping to get some guidance on this.
-I am writing a program that is executing a .bat file when a xml file is dropped into a folder, and then moves the xml file to a done directory.

The problem is that the bat file takes ~10 seconds to run and requires the XML file to be present in the directory, however, my move method is moving the xml file immediately after executing the .bat file command, forcing the .bat file itself to fail.

After researching around, a Thread.Sleep or Task.Delay would be the answer as i would simply like to pause the executing method while the .bat file completes then performs the movefile method however I can not seem to grasp/get the execution to stop for short duration before calling MoveFilesCompleted.MoveComp().

This is what I have but hoping for any advice..

```
 private void _fileWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        if (f.Extension.Equals(".xml") || f.Extension.Equals(".XML"))
        {
            Logger.log(String.Format("File Created: Path: {0}, Name: {1}", e.FullPath, e.Name));

            try
            {
                exBat.executeBAT();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.log(String.Format("Running the XMLtoINF SQLload failed."));
            }

            Thread.Sleep(15000);

            MoveFilesCompleted.MoveComp();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have control of the script being run? Would be helpful if you had a little bit more information about it, there are a lot of ways to do what you need to do and some ways are better than others but need to know how much information you have over the script before I can tell you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `executeBAT` uses the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class to start the BAT file, you can make it wait for that process to exit by calling [Process.WaitForExit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you @adv12. I was not running a WaitForExit() command which forced the command to stay open until finished. I added it after the .Start() and held the bat file until finished.

Answer (score 1):

It would really help if you posted a bit about how you are executing your batch file!

Otherwise check here: [How to wait until my batch file is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682629/how-to-wait-until-my-batch-file-is-finished)